# Weinre console logs aren't shown

Tags: cordova, google-chrome, ember.js, console.log, weinre

I installed the latest version of weinre 2.0.0-pre-I0Z7U9OV. Everything (Elements, Resources, Network) seems to work as expected, except from the console.

My app has lots of `console.log` throughout the JS files, but I cannot see anything in weinre console, even though if I do a `alert('XXX')` in weinre console it shows up in my app. On the other hand if I do a `console.log('test')` in my app's console it shows in weinre. So I guess they are connected, but I don't know why the logs from the JS files aren't shown..

What am I missing?

Other details

- I'm building an Ember.js app
- Currently I'm testing with Chrome: both weinre and my app are opened in 2 tabs on Chrome
- I must use weinre to debug Chrome on iOS since there is no other solution

Answer (score 1):

There are some options to weinre listed on the weinre doc page - https://people.apache.org/~pmuellr/weinre-docs/latest/ - maybe one of those can help.

If not, can you try running the demo here - http://weinre.mybluemix.net/ - run both the weinre debugger UI from that site AND the demo.  The demo does some console.log()'s.  We'll find out if it's a systemic problem or something in your app.

Comment: Thanks for the references! It is very helpful to use   http://weinre.mybluemix.net/. The problem though is caused by the way the Ember.Logger is using the console. What they do boils down to use this type of call for a console.log:     console["log"].apply(console, ["test message 1", "test message 2"]) I think that the event might not be caught by weinre. I'll try to modify the way their calls work.